# WAMP cant accesses www in window 10

Tags: wamp

I install wamp, it was working well and i can access  (http://localhost/www) and after 2 days i update my project ,and try to access www but cannot access www folder and cannot run my project i received following message.

**Not Found
The requested URL /www was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) PHP/5.6.19 Server at localhost Port 80**

can someone help me,

Comment: Have the services been stopped by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately we're not mind readers, so "i tried all" doesn't tell us enough.  Please edit your question and list exactly what you've tried already, and what the results were.  Otherwise this will probably be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `www` folder using the URL `http://localhost/www` because the DocumentRoot by default is the `www` folder, so `http://localhost` points to the www folder.

Unless you create a new folder `wamp\www\www`

Using `http://localhost` should show you the WAMPServer homepage